# Absolute difference of a TimeSpan object with a timing interval in scale of month and year

Tags: c#

I am in some trouble within a simple timing manipulation in C#.

The user defines two `DateTime` objects, as the start and the end of a time interval:

```
DateTime From = new DateTime(Y, Mo, D, H, Mi, S, Ms);
DateTime To = new DateTime(YY, MMo, DD, HH, MMi, SS, MMs);
```

Then a delay parameter, is which a `TimeSpan` object, would be taken into account:

```
TimeSpan delay = new TimeSpan(day, month, hour, second);
```

Now the program should return the deviation of the time interval, corresponding to the `delay` parameter.

Now, there are two problems:

1- Time span has no `Year` and `Month` parameters, whereas the difference between `From` and `To` might be more than `Day`... How can I feed `Year` and `Month` into the `TimeSpan` object?!... (I know that there is no defined constructor for this aim)

2- The final difference, which I try to catch by below code snippet just produces garbage:

```
var diff = (To - From).duration() - delay;
```

How should I resolve this case?!

I am appreciated if anyone can handle above cases...

Comment: What do you mean with `produces garbage`? In general: the `TotalDays` and `Days` properties are not restricted (to month or year) since it's the greatest unit in `TimeSpan` as you've correctly noticed. So this works for example `TimeSpan.FromDays(1000)`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: In this case, the program will detect detect all of the time variances less than 1000 days, won't it?!
I mean the output is totally irrelevant; For example, when the time difference is just one minute, it returns a 2-day-interval as the result!

Comment: A `TimeSpan` value just represents a period of time and has no knowledge of a starting point or ending point.  Because years and months are different lengths, a `TimeSpan` can't have any concept of years and months.  If you want to determine the number of whole years and months between two `DateTime` values then it's up to you to calculate it yourself with some arithmetic.  You may find the `AddYears` and `AddMonths` methods useful.

Answer (score 3):

This is the sort of thing that my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project is designed to handle. It has a [`Period`](http://nodatime.org/api/html/T_NodaTime_Period.htm) type which *does* know about months and years, not just a fixed number of ticks. For example:

```
LocalDateTime start = new LocalDateTime(2014, 1, 1, 8, 30);
LocalDateTime end = new LocalDateTime(2014, 9, 16, 12, 0);
Period delay = new PeriodBuilder { 
        Months = 8, 
        Days = 10,
        Hours = 2,
        Minutes = 20
    }
    .Build();

Period difference = (Period.Between(start, end) - delay).Normalize();
```

Here `difference` would be a period of 5 days, 1 hour, 10 minutes. (The `Normalize()` call is to normalize all values up to days... otherwise you can have "1 hour - 10 minutes" for example.) The `Period` API is going to change a bit for Noda Time 2.0, but it will still have the same basic ideas.)

Comment: That sounds awesome... However I have to handle this without external libraries... Is that possible?!

Comment: @matinking: Well there's nothing similar in the BCL. You'd have to create your own equivalent, which will be a lot of work. Why can't you use external libraries? Do you need the *result* to have months etc? If not, you could just remember the years/months/days/etc and add them to `From`, then take the difference between that and `To`.

Comment: The responsible corporation is doing the project for a private security customer, is which terribly cautious about everything isn't embedded into .NET, intrinsically... Damn it...
Actually I need the full difference, from `Year` to `Minutes`...

Comment: @matinking: Hmm. You're either stuck writing it yourself then, or providing the Noda Time source code to them for review. It feels like a terribly wasteful approach to ignore all open source projects, personally :(

Comment: You're right... I am appreciated due to your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

If you you choose to **round down** and add **extension methods** :

```
public static class Extensions
{
    private const double DaysInYear = 365.242;
    private const double DaysInMonth = 30.4368;
    public static int GetDays(this TimeSpan ts)
    {
        return (int)((ts.TotalDays % DaysInYear % DaysInMonth));
    }
    public static int GetMonths(this TimeSpan ts)
    {
        return (int)((ts.TotalDays % DaysInYear) / DaysInMonth);
    }
    public static int GetYears(this TimeSpan ts)
    {
        return (int)(ts.TotalDays / DaysInYear);
    }
}
```

It would be easy as:

```
var oldDate = new DateTime(2002, 7, 15);
var newDate = new DateTime(2014, 9, 16, 12, 3, 0);
// Difference
var ts = newDate - oldDate;
var dm = ts.Minutes;        //3
var dh = ts.Hours;          //12
var dd = ts.GetDays();      //2
var dM = ts.GetMonths();    //2
var dY = ts.GetYears();     //12
```

Note that this is an **approximation** and would apply only if you can make assumptions that

- DaysInYear = 365.242
- DaysInMonth = 30.4368

are correct.

Comment: This result just returns the day... What if one is eager to all timing units, i.e. year, day, month, in a standard timing format?

Comment: January has 31 days and February can have 28/29 days, if you want months you need extra assumptions. Same would apply for year. To simplify you can assume that 1 month is 30.4368 days, but it depends on what you call accurate.